# How to open a C# Project with no .sln and .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms

I have this old C# project files, I don't know where it came from and all I know is that it's a Webforms app. I'm trying to open it and not get errors about conflicts and incompatibilities.

I have tried opening it as a project/solution web site,
I have go on with them and installed all the references it's 'missing' and it still does not work.

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to create a solution and project file, and then add the code files (and references, nuget packages, etc.) to the project. If this is what you mean by "I have tried ...", then please explain how that doesn't work.

Comment: @John I have created and added all the needed files.. do you mean that I have to create a new project and put all of the files in there?

Comment: Have you tried `File -> Open -> Web Site`? That is one C# 'project type' that doesn't have sln and csproj files.

Comment: @mjwills I did, still wont run

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? any at compile time? any at runtime?